# How does server prioritize which type of web.xml error page to use?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets, custom-error-pages

I have two error pages; 1 is for SpecificExceptionA and the other is for Throwable.

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>org.SpecificExceptionA</exception-type>
  <location>/WEB-INF/views/error/timedout.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
  <location>/WEB-INF/views/error/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

If I have both of these defined in my web.xml everything goes to /error/error.jsp.

If I have just the specific exception defined, it goes to the proper page; but other errors go to the tomcat default (except 404)

Is there a better way to specify specific exception handlers? I'm using spring 3.0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not specific to Tomcat. This is specific to the Servlet API. How the error page is determined is specified in chapter 9.9.2 of [Servlet API specification 2.5](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr154/index2.html). Here's an extract of relevance:

> #### SRV.9.9.2 Error Pages
>
> If no `error-page` declaration containing an `exception-type` fits using the
>   class-hierarchy match, and the exception thrown is a `ServletException` or
>   subclass thereof, the container extracts the wrapped exception, as defined by
>   the `ServletException.getRootCause` method. A second pass is made over the error
>   page declarations, again attempting the match against the error page
>   declarations, but using the wrapped exception instead.

So, your `SpecificExceptionA` was likely wrapped in a [`ServletException`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletException.html) and thus the `java.lang.Throwable` is the closest match on 1st pass. When you remove this entry, a 2nd pass will be made with the wrapped exception and thus your `SpecificExceptionA` get a match.

The right way to define a general HTTP 500 error page is to map it on `error-code` instead of `exception-type`:

```xml
<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.SpecificExceptionA</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/error/timedout.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/error/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

If this is not an option for some unclear reason, one of the ways to workaround this is to create a `Filter` which listens on an `url-pattern` of `/*` and does basically the following:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        Throwable rootCause = e.getRootCause();
        if (rootCause instanceof SpecificExceptionA) {
            throw (SpecificExceptionA) rootCause;
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

It only has to extend from `RuntimeException` to get it to work.

Comment: I'm trying to decide if I want to choose the answer which solves the generic problem or the one that is tied to the framework... Thoughts?

Comment: I don't use Spring and your question was about Tomcat/Servlets in general, hence the generic answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wound up using Springs SimpleMappingExceptionResolver class

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.*.*.ResponseTimeExceededException">
                <!-- the name of the jsp to use for this exception -->
                error/timedout
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="error/error"/>
</bean>
```