# JSF response code when exception ocurrs

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

in my JSF application I throw a `java.lang.SecurityException` when the user is not logged on. In the `web.xml` I redirect to `login.jsf` when a `SecurityException` ocurrs.

Now my problem is that when I look in to the server response, it is a `500 - Internal Server Error`. Can I somehow throw the `SecurityException` and say it should be a `401` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When an exception bubbles up all the way to the servlet container and arrives as an unhandled exception, then it's per definition always a HTTP 500 error. You can't change that part.

You can however control that by catching and suppressing the specific exception somewhere and then explicitly invoke [`HttpServletResponse#sendError()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError-int-), passing the desired 4xx/5xx status code.

On synchronous requests, most sensible place for that would be a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info).

```
try {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
catch (SecurityException e) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, e.getMessage());
}
```

Note: if it's not a `RuntimeException`, catch `ServletException` and inspect its `getRootCause()` instead. See also a.o. [How does server prioritize which type of web.xml error page to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299169/how-does-server-prioritize-which-type-of-web-xml-error-page-to-use/)

On asynchronous (Ajax) requests, you do however need an additional custom exception handler. See also a.o. [Exception handling in JSF ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526753/exception-handling-in-jsf-ajax-requests/). This is of course only relevant if you perform the login via Ajax.

Or, if you already have a servlet filter in place wherein you perform authorization, then just perform `sendError()` instead of throwing `SecurityException`. Provided that your authorization filter look like as the one in [How implement a login filter in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480100/how-implement-a-login-filter-in-jsf/8480241#8480241), then just replace the redirect in the bottom by:

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
```

Either way, it will end up in the error page associated with `<error-code>` of 401.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/unauthorized.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```