# web.xml - multiple exceptions are not handled

Tags: java, error-handling, jboss7.x, web.xml

I have this code in my `web.xml`

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.NoSuchMethodException</exception-type>
    <location>/jsp/errors/noSuchMethodException.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/jsp/errors/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

where I am supposed to handle these exceptions separately but for the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` `error.jsp` is being returned. If I do remove the `java.lang.Exception` section then it works well for `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`.

I am using `JBoss 7 AS`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does server prioritize which type of web.xml error page to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299169/how-does-server-prioritize-which-type-of-web-xml-error-page-to-use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, although the web application is prepared to catch both exceptions, it captures `java.lang.Exception` first.

As a workaround, have you tried to define the second error page (the generic one) with the `500` error code?  It's almost the same as capturing `Exception` and maybe it would work for you...

Comment: Look at this question, because maybe it'll help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299169/how-does-server-prioritize-which-type-of-web-xml-error-page-to-use